# adding async/await to a sequence of JS filters

Tags: javascript

how can I add async & await to this sequence of filters to make sure that the results of one filter is returned before the next filter is called?

```
let rooms = [
  {
    type: "bedroom",
    name: "Caroline",
    utility: {
      size: "90-150",
      shape: "square",
    }

let hasType = async (type, object) => object.type === type;
let resultType = rooms.filter(x => hasType("bedroom", x));
console.log(resultType);

let hasSize = (size, object) => object.utility.size === size;
let resultTypePlusSize = resultType.filter(x => hasSize("90-150", x));
console.log(resultTypePlusSize);

let hasShape = (shape, object) => object.utility.shape === shape;
let resultTypePlusSizePlusShape = resultTypePlusSize.filter(
  x => hasShape("square", x));
console.log(resultTypePlusSizePlusShape);
```

Comment: These are all synchronous functions. Synchronous functions execute in the order that you call them, you don't need to do anything special.

Comment: You shouldn't declare `hasType` to be `async`.

Comment: Just remove the `async` keyword and your code will start working (assuming you also properly close your rooms object and array with `}]`)..

Comment: But remove the "async" from your "hasType" function.

Comment: thanks! yeah, I left that async in there accidentally when I was copy-n-pasting. Thank you for the help. so, it is already synchronous...okay

Answer (score 0):

You could use `reduce` to build up promise chains and then `Promise.all` to execute multiple:

```
 function chain(...mappers) {
   return {
    exec(start) {
      return mappers.reduce((value, fn) => {
        if(value instanceof Promise) {
           return value.then(fn);
        } else {
           return fn(value);
        }
      }, start);
    },
    many(values) {
      return Promise.all(values.map(val => this.exec(val)));
    }
  };
}
```

To be used as:

```
 const transformUsers = chain(
   user => (user.name = "test", user),
   async user => user.name,
   console.log
);

transformUsers.many([{ }, { }]);
```